# Subtraction of church numerals in haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I'm attempting to implement church numerals in Haskell, but I've hit a minor problem. Haskell complains of an infinite type with

Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t = (t -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t2

when I try and do subtraction. I'm 99% positive that my lambda calculus is valid (although if it isn't, please tell me). What I want to know, is whether there is anything I can do to make haskell work with my functions.

```
module Church where

type (Church a) = ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))

makeChurch :: Int -> (Church a)
makeChurch 0 = \f -> \x -> x
makeChurch n = \f -> \x -> f (makeChurch (n-1) f x)

numChurch x = (x succ) 0

showChurch x = show $ numChurch x

succChurch = \n -> \f -> \x -> f (n f x)

multChurch = \f2 -> \x2 -> \f1 -> \x1 -> f2 (x2 f1) x1

powerChurch = \exp -> \n -> exp (multChurch n) (makeChurch 1)

predChurch = \n -> \f -> \x -> n (\g -> \h -> h (g f)) (\u -> x) (\u -> u)

subChurch = \m -> \n -> (n predChurch) m
```

Comment: You should make the type declaration `type Church a = (a -> a) -> a -> a`. Its cleaner, not different.

Comment: Also note that it helps a ton to write out the type signatures. It will tell you exactly where the problem is...

Comment: I ended up removing the type signatures, to see if ghci could infer them properly, and hopefully get rid of the error (the error has not changed)... also, I prefer the parentheses around the type. It makes it stand out more to me

Answer (score 31):

The problem is that `predChurch` is *too polymorphic* to be correctly inferred by Hindley-Milner type inference.  For example, it is tempting to write:

```
predChurch :: Church a -> Church a
predChurch = \n -> \f -> \x -> n (\g -> \h -> h (g f)) (\u -> x) (\u -> u)
```

but this type is not correct.  A `Church a` takes as its first argument an `a -> a`, but you are passing `n` a two argument function, clearly a type error.

The problem is that `Church a` does not correctly characterize a Church numeral.  A Church numeral simply represents a number -- what on earth could that type parameter mean?  For example:

```
foo :: Church Int
foo f x = f x `mod` 42
```

That typechecks, but `foo` is most certainly not a Church numeral.  We need to restrict the type.  Church numerals need to work for *any* `a`, not just a specific `a`.  The correct definition is:

```
type Church = forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
```

You need to have `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` at the top of the file to enable types like this.

Now we can give the type signature we expect:

```
predChurch :: Church -> Church
-- same as before
```

You *must* give a type signature here because higher-rank types are not inferrable by Hindley-Milner.

However, when we go to implement `subChurch` another problem arises:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Church'
       against inferred type `(a -> a) -> a -> a'
```

I am not 100% sure why this happens, I think the `forall` is being too liberally unfolded by the typechecker.  It doesn't surprise me though; higher rank types can be a bit brittle because of the difficulties they present to a compiler.  Besides, we shouldn't be using a `type` for an *abstraction*, we should be using a `newtype` (which gives us more flexibility in definition, helps the compiler with typechecking, and marks the places where we use the implementation of the abstraction):

```
newtype Church = Church { unChurch :: forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a) }
```

And we have to modify `predChurch` to roll and unroll as necessary:

```
predChurch = \n -> Church $ 
    \f -> \x -> unChurch n (\g -> \h -> h (g f)) (\u -> x) (\u -> u)
```

Same with `subChurch`:

```
subChurch = \m -> \n -> unChurch n predChurch m
```

But we don't need type signatures anymore -- there is enough information in the roll/unroll to infer types again.

I always recommend `newtype`s when creating a new abstraction. Regular `type` synonyms are pretty rare in my code.

Comment: As for the `type` error, it happens because in Haskell polymorphic types must be instantiated only with monomorphic type arguments: in `type Church = forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a)` type variable `a` must be monomorphic, but in `subChurch` definition it isn't the case (in `(n predChurch)` type variable `a` is set to `Church` which is polymorphic). Here is detailed explanation: http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#some-impredicativity

Answer (score 7):

This definition of `predChurch` [doesn't work in simply typed lambda calculus](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/lambda-calc.html#predecessor), only in the untyped version. You can find a version of `predChurch` that works in Haskell [here](http://users.info.unicaen.fr/~karczma/Essays/church.html).

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. I was just wondering if there was some sort of magic I could do to make haskell not care about the type. I already have a definition that works in haskell, I just wanted to know if I could get the untyped version to work in haskell. Thanks again.

Comment: @Probie: Keep in mind that the first bit only refers to the simply-typed λ-calculus, which is akin to Haskell without any of: polymorphic types, type classes, `data` and `newtype`, and recursive bindings.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem. And I solved it without adding type signature.

Here's the solution, with `cons` `car` copied from [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

```
cons x y = \m -> m x y
car z = z (\p q -> p)
cdr z = z (\p q -> q)

next z = cons (cdr z) (succ (cdr z))
pred n = car $ n next (cons undefined zero)

sub m n = n pred m
```

You can find full source [here](https://gist.github.com/2413845).

I'm really amazed after writing `sub m n = n pred m`, and load it in ghci without type error!

Haskell code is so concise! :-)

Comment: This doesn't really work. If you look at the inferred types in GHCi, they're too specialized, so e.g. `showChurch $ sub (plus three two) two` gives type errors.

Comment: @hammar Oooops, you are right. I tested `sub two one` only. `sub three two` gives type errors.