How do I solve this infinitely recursive type problem I've created in Haskell with Church Numerals
data ChurchN a = ChurchN
    { numeral :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
    , litRep :: String 
    }

next :: ChurchN a -> ChurchN a
next x = ChurchN 
    {
    numeral = \f y -> f (numeral x f  y)
    , litRep = 
      let (lambx, funct) = splitAt (length "\f x -> ") (litRep x)
      in lambx ++ "f(" ++ funct ++ ")"
    }

plus :: ChurchN a -> ChurchN a -> ChurchN a
plus x y = numeral y next x


main :: IO ()
main = print "hello world" -- this so the code compiles

Here I want to calculate the plus operation by applying next to x, y times.
However, in practice, this creates a recursive infinity type since the type of the function next  becomes self referential.
Of course, this could be worked around by either not using the next function and instead creating a new one(either,I make plus from scratch and add a custom function that generates the literal representation of the numeral, or make it so either x or y are converted to numbers and next is aplayed that number of times) but thats too simple and obvious, I want to know if what im trying to do is possible in the 1st place.
tried changing up the generic types, still got errors because of type missmatch.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595749/subtraction-of-church-numerals-in-haskell covers an issue that people commonly have with Church numerals, in particular the wrong type you have given them (no forall). I haven't closed this as a duplicate because I'm not sure if this is the only issue you're having; if it answers all your questions please feel free to mark it as such.

I can confirm locally that adding forall a. to the type of the numeral field makes this compile.
